# Valid proof by induction for modulus of a product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I want to prove that $$|z_1 z_2 z_3\cdots z_n|=|z_1| | z_2| |z_3|\cdots|z_n|$$

Now this really feels like something I can just throw induction at.

**Base case: $n=2$.**

$|z_1 z_2|=|z_1| |z_2|$ follows directly from expressing these numbers in exponential form.

**Induction hypothesis:**

Now assume that for $\forall k$, we can say that

$|z_1 z_2 z_3\cdots z_k|=|z_1| | z_2| |z_3|\cdots|z_k|$.

**Inductive step:**

Call the product of the first terms $w$

$$|z_1 z_2 z_3\cdots z_k z_{k+1}|=| w \space z_{k+1}|=|w||z_{k+1}|$$

**Now use the induction hypothesis:**

$$|w||z_{k+1}|=|z_1| | z_2| |z_3|\cdots|z_k||z_{k+1}|.$$

The aforementioned theorem holds by the principle of induction. QED

Modulus really feels like a homomorphism like this, did I do my proof correctly, should I elaborate? Is my writing clear? Any tips or recommendations? I really feel induction proofs are a bit rigid sometimes, the interesting ones are the ones where the inductive step isn't straightforward at all and requires some extra skill or inspiration.

Comment: This is correct, but I'm not sure about your base case in the following sense : If it is that obvious, you should be able to express exponential form to the whole product and directly prove your result as easily as your base case. I think that the fact that your base case is using exponential form is actually an application of what you want to prove. I am maybe wrong depending on the definition of complex numbers you are allowed to use.

Comment: We are allowed to use the exponential form for now, but I personally prefer what greedoid posted. It's much more satistfying.

Comment: Then using his definition, I wouldn't go to induction, it seems overkill to me. You can just apply the know corresponding formulas about the square root of you $2n$ terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is perfect. There is nothing to add. Perhaps only this for $n=2$:

$$ |zw| = \sqrt{zw \cdot \overline{zw}} = \sqrt{z\overline{z}}\cdot \sqrt{w\overline{w}} = |z||w|$$

Comment: That is a nice proof using the definition of the metric, complex conjugacy and roots, thank you! simple yet elegant. Exactly what I was looking for.